# Turning Screen Off in Android with PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android, accelerometer, wakelock

I am using the following code to send some HTTP request when the device is moving. It works fine when I change PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK to SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK and it keeps the screen on and app working. However, when using PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, the device locks the screen and the app stops working altogether. I need the screen off so I can save battery usage but changing to PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK doesnt seem to do what it is supposed to.

```
package com.example.sendsms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;


public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    static String TAG = "SendSMS";
    private SensorManager senSensorManager;
    private Sensor senAccelerometer;
    private long lastUpdate;
    private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
    // Wake Locks
    protected static PowerManager mPowerManager;
    protected static PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock1;

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        senSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
        Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

        if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
            float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
            float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

            long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            // only allow one update every 100ms.
            if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 100) {
                long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
                lastUpdate = curTime;

                float speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;
                if (speed > 50) {
                    sendit2();
                }
                last_x = x;
                last_y = y;
                last_z = z;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // can be safely ignored for this demo
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    // Accelerometer Wake Lock
    public static void wakeLock1(boolean up) {
        if (up) {
            mWakeLock1 = mPowerManager.newWakeLock(
                    PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP,
                    "WakeLock:Accelerometer"
            );
            mWakeLock1.acquire();
        } else {
            if (mWakeLock1 != null) {
                if (mWakeLock1.isHeld()) {
                    mWakeLock1.release();
                }
                mWakeLock1 = null;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Get an instance of the SensorManager
        senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        mPowerManager = (PowerManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock1(true);

        // Important 1: You have to provide a way of making the chosen choice look presentable.
        // emailAdapter.setStringConversionColumn(1); // 1=DISPLAY_NAME, 2=Email

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    public void sendit2() {

        String spreadsheetID = "111111111-1111111111111-FP3OQmeVwV";
        String url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/" + spreadsheetID + "/exec";
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        Log.d(TAG, response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "SendSMS Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.sendsms/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "SendSMS Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.sendsms/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sendsms"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
>
        <activity
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:name=".SendSMSActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>


    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"></uses-sdk>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't waste your time. `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` doesn't prevent android to enter in doze mode, as you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html), and thereby sensors activity is suspended or at least delayed. In my tests I've seen that only when the device is connected to power supply the behaviour is the expected.

Comment: I guess so. Although when I connected a sensor to the phone it was working fine the whole time but it drains the bettery in a day so.